# предлог "с" или "в"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как всё-таки правильно сказать: "шишка размером с кулак" или "шишка размером в кулак"? Я думаю, что лучше предлог "с"

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста! )))

При сравнении предметов (наш случай: шишка - кулак), или существ с предметами, или предметов с существами используется только предлог ***с***.

---

[Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

> **РАЗМЕР**
>
> **1. размером в** (при выражении в единицах измерения). *Комната размером в двадцать квадратных метров.*
>
> **2. размером с** (при указании на предмет, к которому приравнивается по величине другой предмет). *Мышь размером с крысу.*